# Sql - Como evitar que los campos vacios de mi formulario aparezcan como undefined al hacer la query?

Tags: sql, ajax

Hola tengo el siguiente problema con una query, tengo un formulario que subo a mi bd pero el usuario tiene la opcion no rellenar todos los campos de el, el problema es que en mi tabla los campos que son varchar se suben como undefined cuando el usuario sube un campo vacio.

Esto me complica cuando yo llamo esos campos para que los edite el usuario ya que aparecen como undefined en vez de vacios.

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?(Uso ajax para enviar los datos al php donde esta la query y son recibidos con el metodo post)

Query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO postulante_26 ( pos_rut, pos_nombre, pos_curso_id ,apo_rut, apo_nombre, apo_parentesco_id, telefono, celular, email, direccion, comuna,  fecha, ano_postulacion, fun_rut, fun_nombre, her_rut, her_nombre, egr_rut, egr_nombre, motivo, motivo_otro) VALUES ('$pos_rut', '$pos_nombre', '$pos_curso', '$apo_rut', '$apo_nombre', '$apo_paren', '$telefono', '$celular', '$email', '$direccion', '$comuna', '$fecha', '$ano', '$funcionario_rut', '$funcionario_nombre', '$hermano_rut', '$hermano_nombre', '$egresado_rut', '$egresado_nombre', '$motivo', '$motivo_otro')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

Comment: Hola @Gustavo, ¿puedes mostrar cómo recuperas los datos que introduce el usuario?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumno where alu_rut = '$rut'";            
$result = array(
                    'rut' => $r->alu_rut,
                    'nombre' =>utf8_encode($r->alu_nombre)                    
                    );
            return($result);
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te sale undefined porque PHP no tiene definida esa variable, antes de lanzar la query checkea los valores, por ejemplo:

**PHP**

```
if(!isset($pos_rut)) {
    $pos_rut = '';
}
```

Así si la variable no está seteada la setearás tu a vacío

Pd: tendrás que hacerlo con todas las variables

Comment: Si no hay valores es más razonable dejar el campo a `null` que como espacios en blanco.

Comment: Ya, pero el usuario quería tener el campo vacío, no null :S

Comment: lo intente recien pero me siguen subiendo los campos undefined en vez de vacios.

Comment: ahi lo arregle, el signo ! estaba demas ya que decia si es verdadero cambia a vacio. Gracias!!

Comment: Si no le pones el !, siempre que tengas esa variable seteada (incluso con valores) te la reemplazará por vacío :S - Lo correcto es "si no está seteada, setéala a vacio" y así no quedará undefined